# Default days for a check depending on run of script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a check which can be run any day of the week. The problem is, it needs to point to a specific day. Currently we have two versions, one to be run Monday for Friday's (00:00 sat) and Tuesday (00:00 Weds) run.

Sometimes the problem we are working on takes more than a day, so it would be nice to be able to run it, say on a Thursday, and the script to say "ah you're looking for the Tuesday run, here's the data.

How would I go about implimenting a `CASE` so it can cherry pick the date?

Currently, this is what the one run on a Monday looks like:

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = dateAdd(dd,-2,GetDate())

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM SummaryBillingDocument
WHERE BillingSessionID
IN (
    SELECT BillingSessionID
    FROM BillingSession
    WHERE DateProduced = @Date)
AND StatementOfAccountID IS NOT NULL
```

This gets run on a Monday and picks up the run at 00:00 on Saturday morning, called the "Friday" run.

I was thinking about a `CASE` but all I came up with was declaring each day and the correct `DatePart` to go with it, I'm not sure that's the best approach

```
case when datename(weekday, getdate()) = 'Friday' then -3
--etc.
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is the best approach IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Closest past day of week?

```
declare @day int = 7; -- Saturday
select  dateadd(day, (@day - datepart(weekday, getdate()) - 7 - @@datefirst) % 7, getdate());
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d461d0b5d4d70f9593a05ee222cffcd9)